# Farseer Physics Bodies In touch (in contact)

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I am new to Farseer, developing a xna + Farseer physics game. There are multiple Physics bodies(square,circle, rectangle shapes) in the game, trying to findout all of the bodies in touch (touching each other), i can calculate based on the width/height but this will not be accurate. i would like to know any other ways or any in built functions in Farseer physics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415522/165500) for a lot of details. You may be able to use one of the events listed in that answer directly, depending on your needs.

But, otherwise, you can get `Contact` objects by either "collecting" them from one of those events, or by extracting them from `Body.ContactList` (which is a linked list made up of `ContactEdge` objects).

Note, of course, that a `Contact` might not actually be *touching* (it just indicates a potential collision). Use `Contact.IsTouching()` to check for that.